# Zariski tangent space in Kempf's Algebraic Varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am having some trouble trying to understand the following statements contained in Kempf's book.
First of all, given $X$ a variety, he defines the tangent space as $T_x X=\text{Spec}(\bigoplus _{n\geq 0}\text{Sym}^n (\text{Cot}_x(X)))$, where $\text{Cot}_x(X)$ is the usual quotient $m_x /{m_x}^2$. He claims that

> clearly $T_x X$ has the same dimension as $\text{Cot}_x X$.

Why is this true? Why is $\text{Cot}_x X$ fintely generated as a vector space in the first place? I guess it is due to some Noetherianess results I don't know.

My second question is about Lemma 6.1.2 (c), stating that

> if $X$ is an affine variety and $n_x$ is the maximal ideal of regular functions vanishing at $x$ then $\text{Cot}_x X = n_x / {n_x}^2$.

In the proof we use that $n_x / {n_x}^2 = (n_x / {n_x}^2)_{n_x}={n_{x_{n_x}}}/{n_{x_{n_x}}^2}=m_x/m_x^2$, but I can't understand the last equality.